# Devexpress gridcontrol checkbox

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, devexpress, gridcontrol

Hello i have a problem with checkbox in gridcontrol(winforms dexexpress). I have three collumns 'Check','Name', 'Descr'. The user can apply sorting on collumn for example 'Name' and then he checked checkbox('Check') on some row. I want to get checked item after i click checkbox on row. But i get wrong index of the row(it is index with default sorting). Any ideas to get right index after applied sorting? The problem is different checkbox are selected after other collumn sorting.
I read about this http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2531 but it not helps me, really dont know how to do it

```
    private void gridViewT_CellValueChanging(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.Name == "CheckColumn" && e.RowHandle > -1)
    {
        if (e.Value != null && (bool)e.Value) {
            DataRow dr = ((DataTable)gridControlT.DataSource).Rows[e.RowHandle];
            DoSomeThing(dr);
        }
    }
}
```

So the e.RowHandle(which means index to table) is after sorting by another collumn old. The CheckColumn which is column with checkboxes is not sorted by another collumn.

Comment: It is not quite clear what do you mean with "i get wrong index of the row"? Please post your code and describe the behavior you expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the correct code:

```
//DataRow dr = ((DataTable)gridControlT.DataSource).Rows[e.RowHandle];
DataRow dr = ((GridView)sender).GetDataRow(e.RowHandle);
```

Row handle gets the **handle(not the index)** of the row that contains the processed cell.
Row handles define the order in which rows are displayed within a View. **This order takes into account any sorting and filtering settings applied to the View**.

Related help-article : [Identifying Rows and Cards](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument642)

Comment: +1 I was about to post the same, You just did:) I suppose sometimes `GetDataRow` returns `DataRowView` isn't it?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I believe it is true for ColumnView.GetRow method and false for ColumnView.GetDataRow method. From [documentation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetRowtopic): If the data source is a System.Data.DataTable or a System.Data.DataView, this method returns a System.Data.DataRowView object. If the data source is a custom list of items, the appropriate list item is returned.

Comment: So casting to `DataRow` would fail need to check the return value

Comment: @SriramSakthivel It may be...I believe, for each specific case it is better to ask the DevExpress Support guys [directly](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/)...from my experience their answers are very fast and comprehensive